# Unknown Reader in SCardGetStatusChange Winscard

Tags: vb.net, smartcard, contactless-smartcard, winscard

I am new to.net and I would like to identify if card is detected or removed using winscard's SCardGetStatusChange. But it is returning retcode = -2146435063 which when converted to Hex would give me 0x80100009 = SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_READER. I just based my code from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.SCardGetStatusChange)

Here's sample of my code

```
Public Structure SCARDREADER_STATE
    Public szReader As String
    Public pvUserData As IntPtr
    Public dwCurrentState As Integer
    Public dwEventState As Integer
    Public cbAtr As Integer
    Public rgbAtr() As Byte
End Structure

<DllImport(winscarddll, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint:="SCardGetStatusChangeA")>
Public Shared Function SCardGetStatusChange(ByVal hContext As IntPtr, ByVal dwTime As Integer, ByRef rgReaderState As SCARDREADER_STATE(), ByVal cReaders As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

And in my form.

```
Public Function gAtr(ByVal hContext As IntPtr, ByVal reader As String) As String
    Dim ret As Integer
    Dim rs(0) As WinscardFun.SCARDREADER_STATE
    Console.Write(reader)
    'ReDim rs(0).rgbAtr(0 To 35)
    'rs(0).dwEventState = &H0
    'rs(0).rgbAtr = Nothing
    'rs(0).cbAtr = 0
    rs(0).szReader = reader ' "\\\\?PnP?\\Notification"
    rs(0).dwCurrentState = SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE

    ret = WinscardFun.SCardGetStatusChange(hContext, 100000000, rs, 1)
    Console.Write("Ret=" + ret.ToString + vbCrLf)
    Console.Write("Reader:" + rs(0).szReader + vbCrLf)
    If ret = 0 And rs(0).cbAtr > 0 And rs(0).rgbAtr IsNot Nothing Then
        test = "Success"
    Else
        test = "Fail"
    End If

    Return test
End Function
```

The output is

> Ret=-2146435063
>   Reader:ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader PICC 0
>   Fail

Comment: are you sure you have driver for card reader install ? did you ever successful using your card reader via other app tools on your machine ?

Comment: Yes, in fact I was successfully use the scardconnect and scardreaderlist. Therefore I am sure that the reader is working properly. I just want to use the scardgetstatuschange to identify if card is detected or not.

Comment: could you provide result from 
SCardListReaders

Comment: The reader name you used is not correct.  Doubling the backslashes like that is something you'd do in a language like C or C#, not in VB.NET

Comment: @WallSkyBlue I am using ACR1222L, the results are:ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader PICC 0
ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader SAM 0
ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader SAM 1
ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader SAM 2

Comment: @HansPassant The '\\\\?PnP?\\Notification' refers to the manual from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379773(v=vs.85).aspx) but I didn't use it thats why I just add it to comment section.

Comment: uh ..... then I think your reader name in `ByVal reader As String` should be "ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader"

Comment: @WallSkyBlue thanks but still not working. Still giving unknown card

Comment: I finally solved by adding <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=36)> on my rgbAtr. Haha. phew

Comment: You might want to use [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) or have a look at their way doing it.

Answer (score 0):

For future researcher/developer.

In SCardGetStatusChange, I just changed the SCardReaderState() to SCardReader

```
<DllImport(winscarddll, EntryPoint:="SCardGetStatusChangeA", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Public Shared Function SCardGetStatusChange(ByVal hContext As IntPtr, ByVal dwTime As Integer, ByRef rgReaderState As SCARDREADER_STATE, ByVal cReaders As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

Then added the `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=36)>` in the initialization of rgbAtr.

Hope this will helps.